# How to install module from code python3.7.1

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install modules with python

This is what I have tried:

```py
def install(package):
    os.system("python  -m pip install " + package)
install("winsound")
```

But I got an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winsound(from versions: none)
```

Comment: [`winsound`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) is a stdlib module installed with every standard Python build (at least on Windows). There is no need to pip install it

Comment: You haven't stated your OS. It only works on Windows, and if you are on Windows, you'll already have it

Comment: winsound isnt the only one, and windows.

Comment: Well can you give an example that isn't part of the standard library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by trying to install modules in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised as you are trying to install modules from Standard Python Library.

You can read more about them from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/